# Web сервис в .NET

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, .net, веб-служба

Здравствуйте. Сейчас я задам наверное очень глупый вопрос поэтому просьба не слишком ругаться. Как известно на C# можно создавать веб-сервисы, которые представляют собой файлы asmx. А теперь глупый вопрос: а зачем они нужны? Разве клиент-серверное web-приложение не может обеспечить выполнение запросов пользователя с клиента на сервер и получение пользователем результатов?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/74472/net-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0-asmx-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0-wcf

Comment: Вопрос "Зачем нужны веб-сервисы?" выходит за рамки C# и .NET

В качестве примера прикладного использования веб-сервисов в "обычных" веб-приложениях (WebForms) можно привести сервис для "общения" клиентской (JS) части сайта через AJAX с сервером. Довольно удобно иметь один или несколько сервисов, предоставляющих сгруппированные по смыслу методы, нежели городить огород из хэндлеров (ashx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Веб-сервис - это аналог библиотеки(*.dll), только работающий по интернету.